# Which hybrid mobile app framework to use

Tags: hybrid-mobile-app

I know that hybrid apps are much easier to use, so I need to choose a best one for my application that I already have as website, done in PHP. These are my options:
1.PhoneGap
2.AppDeck
3.Titanium
4.Ionic

Any suggestions on which is the best one to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use PhoneGap since it is the most mature one.

Answer (score 0):

Ionic is pretty much based on Cordova (which is based on PhoneGap)

But i'd go for Ionic from that list, seems to have lots of support being it and are adding stuff to it regularly.

Answer (score 0):

From this I will recommend you Ionic.
It's as phonegap build on Cordova but Ionic seems to be the most hot hybrid platform right now